# how to draw a normal text by art(ReactNative)?

Tags: canvas, react-native

I am using React-Native ART to draw some charts, but there does not have enough doc about it.

```
<Text
  x={200}
  stroke="#000"
  font={{
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 100,
  }}
  text="R..ksk"
>
  React....
</Text>
```

[image]

How can I just draw a simple text like "React..." without bold and box.

[image]

Comment: Did you want the first or second screenshotted result?

Comment: @RyanTurnbull the second

Answer (score 0):

I had got the answer. remove the stroke and add fill

```
<Text
  x={200}
  fill="#000"
  font={{
    fontSize: 20,
    fontFamily: 'Arial',
    fontWeight: 100,
  }}
>
  React....
</Text>
```